# Apple Appstore Submission: Different apps with same name - for different regions

Tags: app-store

Can we submit different apps with the same name for different regions?

For example, for a MNC, can we submit an app for say US, and a different app (for the same company - so same name) - for say UK?

I searched in the net, but couldnt find any link relevant to this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the app name in iTunes Connect is unique, so you will have to differentiate, perhaps by adding the region to the name, e.g. My App - US and My App - UK