# Uploading app binary to itunes

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, app-store-connect

I have complete my app and submit the app to app store successfully, when I look it in my iTunes connect, it shows waiting for review. so there is a button named view in iTunes. I clicked that button to see my app in iTunes, but there comes the problem. there popups a message that it wil to available in my iTunes, it is currently only available in us store. I am from India. it shows it will not available in Indian market. but I didn't do anything with my location, the app I uploaded is for world wide not for US only.

what is the problem with this. this is my first app submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be like that till your app gets approved. It will not show your app in iTunes because it is not available to download yet. The message is misleading but it really means your app is not available at all. There is nothing to worry about. I'm also not from US and i had this with every app i submitted.

Comment: ohh god ,thanks for the reply..am really worried about this problem.hehe.i have one more question,my application product name is CrawlingZombies but i put CrawlingZombie1 in itues connect.which wil come in iTunes when this app is approved by the apple?

Comment: @stackiphone What field did you put "CrawlingZombie1" in?

Comment: AFAIK it will be `CrawlingZombie1` on iTunes and `CrawlingZombies` on device. You can change the iTunes name by altering the localized metadata.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle in application name field of iTunes connect.i need this name to come in appstore instead of product name

Comment: @Adam so the product name will come in a Appstore?

Comment: @Adam ohh my god,there is a same product name available in appstore .how to change this or edit this?plz help me.i thought the iTunes app field name will comes inappstore.thats why i changed it here.

Comment: @stackiphone I have never done this myself. This link is a little help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075416/apple-appstore-submission-different-apps-with-same-name-for-different-regions. The last thing you can do is adding some character at the end of the name, like `CrawlingZombies!` or `CrawlingZombies*`. You can also try `Crawling Zombies` with space or google about using emoticons in app name.

Comment: @Adam i have to change it in my iTunes connect o in application product name?so if it is in application product name,i have to up lode the binary once more na?

Comment: @stackiphone You change the name in `Metadata and Uploads` section. You don't need to reupload your binary.

Answer (score 1):

Has the app finished the review process? This typically takes 7 days. The app won't be in any national store until the review process is complete.

If you try to view an app in itunes before it is released you get a popup informing you that the app is not available in the U.S store. I suspect you read this popup incorrectly.

If you want to double check, open the app on itunes connect and go to 'Rights and Pricing' on the top right. You'll be able to see all the relevant info here, including the stores it will be released to once the review process is complete.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are correct, but the only other thing I can think of is a problem with your apps rating because of local laws:

E.x.

[image]

My apologies if this doesn't pertain to you, but I'm not familiar with what the United Arab Emirates is.